# I am facing trouble in adding data using SQLite database

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to insert some information of cars using 3 EditTexts in my xml page and by creating table SQLite database and an error occurs in logcat:

```
  Process: com.example.sqlite, PID: 7264
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:102)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:259)
        at com.example.sqlite.MyDatabaseHelper.addCar(MyDatabaseHelper.kt:58)
        at com.example.sqlite.AddActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(AddActivity.kt:15)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
```

here is my Database Creation:

```
private val context:Context? = null

private const val TABLE_NAME = "my_CarShow"
private const val COLUMN_ID = "_id"
private const val COLUMN_NAME = "car_name"
private const val COLUMN_TYPE = "car_type"
private const val COLUMN_MODEL = "car_model"
const val DATABASE_NAME: String = "CarShow.db"
const val DATABASE_VERSION: Int = 1


class MyDatabaseHelper(context: Context?) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {





    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {

        val query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_MODEL + " INTEGER)"
        db!!.execSQL(query)

    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {

        db!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_NAME")
        onCreate(db)
    }

    fun addCar(name:String, type:String, model:String){

        var db = this.writableDatabase
        var cv = ContentValues()

        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME,name)
        cv.put(COLUMN_TYPE,type)
        cv.put(COLUMN_MODEL,model)

        var result =  db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, cv)

        if (result == -1L){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(context,"Added Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the activity that the data must be iserted or added :

```
class AddActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add)

        add_button.setOnClickListener {
            val myDb = MyDatabaseHelper(this)
            myDb.addCar(name_input.text.toString(),
                        type_input.text.toString(),
                model_input.text.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

what can I do to solve this error?
Thanks for your attention

Comment: May I ask why you are not using room? That would make your situation a lot easier

Comment: Please share the contents of the layout file as well

Comment: remove your toast and try again, I guess you are trying to create a toast from a null context